# Visual Studio Code compiling error

Tags: c++

I am totally new to coding. I started with a simple hello word program. I can not run it tho.I think i have to edit the launch.json file.

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
    {
        "name": "(Windows) Launch",
        "type": "cppvsdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "enter program name, for example \${workspaceRoot}/a.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "\${workspaceRoot}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": true
    }
}
```

My hello word code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
std::cout << "Hello World!";
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Your question is tagged [C++]. What does JSON have to do with anything?

Comment: Did you try reading the template JSON file? It tells you exactly how it needs to be edited.

Comment: As i said,i have no clue. In the .json file it says something about a file location

Comment: You seem to be using Visual Studio Code, which AFAIK doesn't come with a C++ compiler included. I'd recommend downloading Visual Studio Community if you're on Windows, or looking into g++ if not.